# How to get post params in HttpAsyncRequestHandler

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I'm using Apache HttpCore HttpAsyncRequestHandler to handle POST requests.
How can I get params submitted by form?

Comment: Share what you have tried.

Comment: @stokito: What is the format of the request entity? URL encoded form? Multipart from (MIME)?

Answer (score 0):

The post body in available in the handler. `EntityUtils.toByteArray(httpRequest.getEntity())` would give you the entire data.

I didnt find any generic utility to parse this.
I wrote a custom parser which could get me params and any uploaded file.

The below code gets me the params in params map and file content in output. It will crash for huge files as all the data is in memory. (warning: WIP)

```
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String currentLine = reader.readLine();
        String boundary = currentLine;

        while(reader.ready()) {
            currentLine = reader.readLine();
            if (currentLine.contains("Content-Disposition: form-data;")) {
                String paramName = currentLine;
                paramName = paramName.replace("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=","").replace("\"","");
                StringBuilder paramValue = new StringBuilder();
                if(paramName.contains("filename")) {
                    String[] temp = paramName.split(";");
                    paramName = temp[0];
                    paramValue.append(temp[1].replace("filename", "").replace("=", "").replace(" ", ""));
                } else {
                    currentLine = reader.readLine();
                    while(!currentLine.contains(boundary)) {
                        paramValue.append(currentLine);
                        currentLine = reader.readLine();
                    }
                }
                params.put(paramName, paramValue.toString());
            }
            if (currentLine.contains("Content-Type: ")) {
                // File Content here
                reader.readLine();

                String prevLine = reader.readLine();
                currentLine = reader.readLine();

                //writing the data to a output stream
                while (true) {
                    if (currentLine.contains(boundary)) {
                        output.write(prevLine.getBytes());
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        output.write(currentLine.getBytes());
                    }
                    prevLine = currentLine;
                    currentLine = reader.readLine();
                }

            }
        }
```